# Why observable is not observed

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I have two level observables and the code looks like this:

```
function level_1() {
    ...
    level_2(params).subscribe((value) => {
        if (value === something) {
            action_1();
        }
        else { // others
            action_2();
        }
    });
}

function level_2(params) : Observable<any> {
    ...

    another_observable.subscribe((v) => {
        if (a_condition) {
            return of(something); // this is reached, but the observable is not captured
        }
        else {
            return of (others);
        }
    });

    return of(others); // this is captured
}
```

Now the problem is, among the three "return of", only the third one is captured in level_1, but the first one is reached in level_2, but not captured in level_1.
I though observable will keep listening, is there anything I am missing?

Comment: What is `others`. And why do you thing `return of(something)` should return something in `level_2`? That's a completely different function. They don't have to do anything with each other ...

Comment: We can think here something is "true", while others is "false". My question is, why return of(true) is not captured in the level_1 function.

Comment: Why do you think it should. `another_observable.subscribe` does have nothing to do with the observable returned by `level_2`

Comment: So it there anyway I can have another_observable to emit something which can be captured by level_1: level_2(params).subscribe((value) {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an observable from `level_2`, which can then be subscribed to in `level_1`:

```js
function level_1() {
  level_2().subscribe(value => {
    if (value === 'something') {
      console.log('action_1')
    }
    else {
      console.log('action_2')
    }
  })
}

const another_observable = of(true) // This is just to make this example work

function level_2() {
  return another_observable.pipe(
    switchMap(value => {
      if (value) {
        return of('something')
      }
      else {
        return of('others')
      }
    })
  )
}

level_1()
```

...or you can use `map` instead of `switchMap` if you just need to switch to a value rather than another observable:

```js
function level_2() {
  return another_observable.pipe(
    map(value => {
      if (value) {
        return 'something'
      }
      else {
        return 'others'
      }
    })
  )
}
```